# java.awt.Image to itextpdf.text.Image does not works

Tags: java, maven, itext, barcode

Hi i am creating a barcode but when i create a code this return me a AwtImage, and when i try parse to itextpdf.text.Image this make me an error and y cant compile mi code this is my barcode generator

```
import com.itextpdf.barcodes.Barcode128;
import com.itextpdf.text.Image;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;

public Image getImage(){
        try{
            Barcode128 code128 = new Barcode128(null);
            code128.setCode("P662130002");
            code128.setBarHeight(80f);
            java.awt.Image awtImage = code128.createAwtImage(Color.WHITE, Color.BLACK);
            Image img = Image.getInstance(awtImage);
            return img;
        }catch(Exception e){
            return null;
        }
    }
```

here is my maven dependencies

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.itextpdf</groupId>
        <artifactId>kernel</artifactId>
        <version>7.0.0</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.itextpdf</groupId>
        <artifactId>io</artifactId>
        <version>7.0.0</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.itextpdf</groupId>
        <artifactId>layout</artifactId>
        <version>7.0.0</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.itextpdf</groupId>
        <artifactId>forms</artifactId>
        <version>7.0.0</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.itextpdf</groupId>
        <artifactId>pdfa</artifactId>
        <version>7.0.0</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.itextpdf</groupId>
        <artifactId>pdftest</artifactId>
        <version>7.0.0</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.18</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.itextpdf/barcodes -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.itextpdf</groupId>
    <artifactId>barcodes</artifactId>
    <version>7.0.1</version>
</dependency>
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.itextpdf/itextpdf -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.itextpdf</groupId>
    <artifactId>itextpdf</artifactId>
    <version>5.1.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Why are you mixing iText 5.1.1 (a mighty old iText version) with iText 7.0.1 (the latest and newest version)? That doesn't make sense. Fix that first: decide whether you want to use iText 5 or iText 7 because they are very different. Then focus on the actual problem.

Comment: thanks for the annotation! i change the version to the 7 thanks again!

Comment: You are mixing the barcodes module version 7.0.1 with other iText 7.0.0 modules. While this may perhaps work, it is not recommended and not supported. It is strongly recommended that all of your artifacts of iText Core/Community are of the same version.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this you must put an extra parameter, this code is the next

```
import com.itextpdf.barcodes.Barcode128;
import com.itextpdf.text.Image;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;

public Image getImage(){
        try{
            Barcode128 code128 = new Barcode128(null);
            code128.setCode("P662130002");
            code128.setBarHeight(80f);
            java.awt.Image awtImage = code128.createAwtImage(Color.WHITE, Color.BLACK);
            Image img = Image.getInstance(awtImage);
            return img;
        }catch(Exception e){
            return null;
        }
    }
```